# Solving double and triple definite integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I was suppose to do these for an assignment last week but I have never done double or triple integrals...I have only double single integrals and they were sooooo much easier..I was stuck on these for hours and decided not to hand the assignment in because I couldn't do a single one. I know I will need to know this for an exam so I was hoping if someone here could explain how to do 1 from question 1 and 1 from question 2. I am trying to approach the integration the same way I did single integrals but I don't even see where to start...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $1(a)$, let evaluate the inner inetgral: $$\int_0^{y^2}y^3e^{xy}dx$$ As we are supposed to do this integral with respect to $x$, so we can assume that $y$ is playing like a constant. So I let $y^3$ to come out of the rest, so we have $$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^{y^2}y^3e^{xy}dx\right)dy\longrightarrow \int_0^1y^3\left(\int_0^{y^2}e^{xy}dx\right)dy$$ But $$\int e^{xy}dx=\frac{1}{y}e^{xy}+C\Longrightarrow y^3\int_0^{y^2}e^{xy}dx=y^2e^{xy}\bigg|_0^{y^2}=y^2(e^{y^3}-1)$$ Now, we finish the job by doing the whole integral: $$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^{y^2}y^3e^{xy}dx\right)dy=\int_0^1y^2(e^{y^3}-1)dy$$ I think you can do the rest. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'll do 1(b) to illustrate changing the order of integration.  Sketch the line $y=x$.  Clearly, the inner integral (over $y$) is over a vertical line segment from a point on that line up to $y=\pi$.  To change the order of integration, note that the region is bounded on the left by the line $x=0$ and the right by $x=y$.  So we may rewite the integral as

$$\int_0^{\pi} dy \frac{\sin{y}}{y} \int_0^y dx $$

Perhaps you can do this one and see how much easier it is.

2(b) could also use a change in integration order with the inner two integrals.  That is,

$$\int_0^1 dy \, \int_{2 y}^2 dx \, \cos{(x^2)} = \int_0^2 dx \, \cos{(x^2)} \, \int_0^{x/2} dy$$

The integral over $z$ may be done separately.